# Matrix in which rows are coordinates of points of a meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mesh

In [this tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.07-support-vector-machines.html) I find code like

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x) 
xy = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
print(xy)
```

**Isn't there a shorter way to get a matrix where rows are coordinates of points of the meshgrid, than using `meshgrid`+`vstack`+`ravel`+`transpose`?**

Output:

```
[[-5.         -1.        ]
 [-5.         -0.77777778]
 [-5.         -0.55555556]
 [-5.         -0.33333333]
 [-5.         -0.11111111]
 [-5.          0.11111111]
 [-5.          0.33333333]
 [-5.          0.55555556]
 [-5.          0.77777778]
 [-5.          1.        ]
 [-4.47368421 -1.        ]
 [-4.47368421 -0.77777778]
 ...
```

Comment: Numpy.repeat() for x and numpy.tile() for y coordinate.

Comment: @ante can you post it as an answer with code example?

Comment: @Bajs I posted answer with a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using `meshgrid`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
xy = np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij'), -1).reshape(-1, 2)
print(xy)
```

Comment: Nice solution @ChrisFlesher!

Comment: You can extend this to 3D also, `xyz = np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij'), -1).reshape(-1, 3)`

Answer (score 2):

You can skip `meshgrid` and get what you want more directly by just taking the [cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of `x` and `y`:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
xy = np.array(list(product(x,y)))
print(xy)
```

Output:

```
[[-5.         -1.        ]
 [-5.         -0.77777778]
 [-5.         -0.55555556]
 [-5.         -0.33333333]
 [-5.         -0.11111111]
 [-5.          0.11111111]
 [-5.          0.33333333]
 [-5.          0.55555556]
 [-5.          0.77777778]
 [-5.          1.        ]
 [-4.47368421 -1.        ]
 [-4.47368421 -0.77777778]
 [-4.47368421 -0.55555556]
 [-4.47368421 -0.33333333]
...
]
```

Comment: This works, but I wonder about the performance (when working with very big arrays) because here we are converting numpy arrays to stdlib python lists, and then back to a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is implementation with repeat and tile methods.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
xy = np.empty((len(x) * len(y), 2))
xy[:, 0] = np.repeat(x, len(y))
xy[:, 1] = np.tile(y, len(x))
print(xy)
```

I suppose meshgrid method uses same approach to fill it's result matrix.

Comment: For future reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html